# How to show custom page for each .jpg image in directory

Tags: javascript, php, html

I currently have a image uploader that uplaods images to my directory on my server. I wish to make it so I can do what a website such as lightshot does with images that are uploaded:

http://prntscr.com/3l83lw

I only want to center the image with a black background, I don't need anything fancy.

Any ideas on how I would go on about doing this?

Comment: We are here to HELP with programming problems. We are not here to do your job for you. YOU write some code, we'll try to help fix it.

Comment: I have no idea were to start. I'm not asking for handed code. I asked for ideas

Comment: you can try this jQuery library http://visuallightbox.com/

Answer (score 0):

what you're trying to accomplish is relatively easy.
You do need html/css/javascript/php knowledge in order to
accomplish it.

start reading tutorials such as these two:
http://www.lateralcode.com/create-a-simple-picture-gallery-using-php/

http://www.johnboy.com/blog/tutorial--php-photo-gallery-with-no-database

good luck !

Comment: Instead of displaying them all on the same page, I want to be able to link an image using php and have it show the page such as www.xx.com/php.php?=image here

Comment: great, go for it. make some code, then post it here if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Make a index page that collects the data after the '/'. 
Takes that word, number or whatever, and matches it with the image uploaded in your server. Then you can display that image in the screen, inside a default page, for all users.